# FireBase's OCR api Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an app (using Flutter) that detects text on images, my app was working perfectly with no problem.
somehow tomorrow my app stopped detecting texts on real device (I tried many different devices and tried deleting play services cache ) but still works in emulator,

in debug mode it gives me this error:

```
> Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0
D/TextNativeHandle(12994): Cannot load feature, fall back to load whole module.
W/DynamiteModule(12994): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12994): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:2702
I/DynamiteModule(12994): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 2702
V/DynamiteModule(12994): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/DynamiteModule(12994): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12994): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0
E/Vision  (12994): Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: gg: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/Vision  (12994): Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
I/GRALLOC (12994): LockFlexLayout: baseFormat: 11, yStride: 1280, ySize: 921600, uOffset: 921600,  uStride: 1280
I/Vision  (12994): Loading library libocr.so
I/Vision  (12994): libocr.so library load status: false
I/Vision  (12994): Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
I/GRALLOC (12994): LockFlexLayout: baseFormat: 11, yStride: 1280, ySize: 921600, uOffset: 921600,  uStride: 1280
W/DynamiteModule(12994): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12994): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0
```

and here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.restless.gsmservices">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="nameofapp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="label, ocr" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

and here is app level dependences:

```
 def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.restless.gsmservices"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

}
```

here is project level dependence:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried for about 8 hours and still had no luck,

please if someone could help me.

Comment: did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: no, I am still struggling